# Datalist options in child component won't update when props are changed through parent component's setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The parent component updates its state with retrieved list from database using `setState`.The state is passed to its child component via props. When the parent's state is updated, the datalist in the child component is still empty list.

Parent component:

```
export default class Major extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                uni: []
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {

            axios.get('http://localhost:3001/uni').then((res) => {
                this.setState({uni: res.data})
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log('something wrong occured: ' + e)
            })
        }
        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <Datalsit_ list={this.state.uni} list_id='abc' />
                </div>

            )
        }
    }
```

Childe component:

```
export default function Datalist({list_id, list}){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" list={list_id} />
            <datalist id={list_id} >
            { list.map((each) => {
                <option value={each} />
            })}
            </datalist>
        </div>
    )
}
```

What part goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are typos in your code (in your parent Datalist is spelled as Datalsit_ )... Having said that... Here is your parent component:

```
export default class Major extends Component {
  state = { uni: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/uni')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ uni: res.data });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('something wrong occured: ' + e);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DataList list={this.state.uni} list_id="abc" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have no idea why you're passing the `list_id prop as the string 'abc'` but that's beside the point...

Here is your Child component:

```
export default function Datalist({ list_id, list }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" list={list_id} />
      <datalist id={list_id}>
        {list.map((each, i) => {
          return <option key={i} value={each} />;
        })}
      </datalist>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note the `return` before the `<option />`... And I'm assuming the value is probably an object so in the datalist you're going to see `[object, Object]` It needs to be `value={each.something}` (I have no idea what as I can't see the structure of the data coming from the API at `http://localhost:3001/uni`)

Again, I have no idea why you would put a `list prop on your input`... but in any case, this should fix it...